# How To: Android OpenCV VideoCapture with File

Tags: android, c++, opencv, video, video-capture

I am trying to pass a video to the OpenCV VideoCapture class. However when I call the `VideoCapture.isOpened()` method it always returns `false`. I have tried two methods:

1. Saving the video file to the internal memory, `context.getFilesDir()` => /data/data/package_name/files/VideoToAnalyze/Recording.mp4
2. and also one to `environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` => sdcard/appName/Recording.mp4.

Nothing seems to work here. My question is how do I pass a video file (or what is the correct file path) to a VideoCapture OpenCV object? I've posted some code below as an example. Note that I don't get an error. The file is always found/exists, but when I call `isOpened()` I always get `false`.

UPDATE:
So it looks like everyone on the web is saying that OpenCV (I'm using 3.10) is lacking a ffmpeg backend and thus cannot process videos. I'm wondering does anyone know this as a fact ?? And is there a work around. Almost all other alternatives to process videos frame by frame is deathly slow.

```
String x = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File dir = new File(x + "/VideoToAnalyze");
if(dir.isDirectory()) {
       videoFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording1.mp4");
} else {
      // handle error
}

if(videoFile.exits(){

     String absPath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
     VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture();
     try{
           vc.open(absPath);
     } catch (Exception e) {
       /// handle error
     }

     if(!vc.isOpened(){
         // this code is always hit
         Log.v("VideoCapture", "failed");
     } else {
         Log.v("VideoCapture", "opened");


    .....
```

Comment: Also just wanted to note .. I tried using some JNI code instead ... still no luck... tried / as well as \ ..         jboolean Java_package_name_videoCapture
        (JNIEnv* env, jobject t)
{
    cv::VideoCapture* videoCapture = new cv::VideoCapture("\\data\\data\\matterandform.net.bevel_android\\files\\VideoToAnalyze\\BevelRecording1.mp4");
    return videoCapture->isOpened();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this .. I downloaded JavaCV .. included .so files into the android project and then used FFMPEGFrameGrabber.

Comment: How was the speed of the above solution compared to the  MediaMetadataRetriever?

Answer (score 3):

Its an old question but nevertheless I had same issue.

Opencv for Android only supports MJPEG codec in AVI container. [See this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/126732/loading-video-files-using-videocapture-in-android/)